# No se muestra texto HTML en navegador Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

En sitio web https://www.maipoadventure.cl/, en pie de página no se muestra el número de celular en navegador SAFARI solo aparace "celular:" y el número sale en blanco. En Chrome se ve el texto bien, puede ser la tipografía?[image: <code>introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí</code>]

```html
<p>Celular: + 56 9 77973724</p>
<p>Email: contacto@maipoadventure.cl </p>
```

Gracias

Comment: si los enlaces tienen color blanco, es que safari le está poniendo un enlace al teléfono para que puedas marcar directamente.

Answer (score 1):

Veo lo mismo, no creo que sea la fuente pero puedes cambiarla y hacer la prueba.

Buscando en el código fuente encontré la clase que contiene el estilo; se llama `.extreme-left p` y puedes allí agregar `!important` al color para que tomen precedencia sobre otras reglas de estilos que se puedan encontrar en la página.

---

**Actualizado:**
Buscando un poco por la web llegue a encontrar esto: `x-apple-data-detectors` que se usa internamente en algunas aplicaciones de Apple en iOS y macOS para insertar automáticamente enlaces para ciertos tipos de información (como números de teléfono, fechas y ubicaciones).

Por otro lado cuando uses números, trata de hacerlo así: `<p>Celular: +56.9.77973724</p>` con puntos o con guiones.

```
a [x-apple-data-detectors]{
color: inherit !important;
}

-----------------------------------------------------

.extreme-left p {
color: black !important; // le agregas !important
margin-top: 3.5%;
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: lo acabo de cambiar pero aún persiste el error, gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: No tienes de que, pero fijate que en algún lado debe haber una clase que contenga color blanco y si esta por arriba de `.extreme-left p`, la posición también influye

Comment: Ahí actualice el código, espero pueda serte útil